# PL/R does not find shared library after install on postgres 9.2

Tags: postgresql, installation, plr

I am trying to get [PL/R](http://www.joeconway.com/plr) running on a linux server where I do not have root access. The installation itself works fine using the command below:

`LD_INCLUDE_PATH="$HOME/pgsql/include" LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$HOME/pgsql/lib:$HOME/lib/R/lib" PGDATA="$HOME/usr/pgsql/data" PG_LIB_DIR="$HOME/pgsql/lib" R_HOME="$HOME/lib/R" USE_PGXS=1 make`

When I try to add the plr extension to a database with `CREATE EXTENSION plr;` however, I get the following error:

`ERROR:  could not load library "~/lib/postgresql/plr.so": libR.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

I read on the bottom of the [install documentation page](http://www.joeconway.com/plr/doc/plr-install.html) that I should add the library path to the LD config file `/etc/ld.so.conf`, but I do not have root access and I can not change this file.

Is there a workaround for this?

thanks in advance

Comment: Can you clarify - is your PG server running as you, or as postgres? If postgres, then $HOME won't be yours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$HOME/pgsql/lib:$HOME/lib/R/lib"` at run-time in the PostgreSQL server's environment. Since you appear to be running PostgreSQL out of your home directory under your own user ID that should be as easy as exporting the environment variable before running `pg_ctl`, eg:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$HOME/pgsql/lib:$HOME/lib/R/lib" pg_ctl -D the_datadir start
```

Alternately you could see if you can re-compile PL/R with rpath linking enabled, so `plr.so` has a path to `libR.so` embedded in it by the linker at compile time. Pass the `-rpath` option in `LDFLAGS` or pass `-Wl,-rpath` in `CFLAGS`. See `-rpath` in `man ld` and `-Wl` in `man gcc`.

Comment: great thanks, the start command above solved the problem. I am going to play around with the `rpath` flag too. With the above command I got another error, but I think its unrelated to this question: `ERROR:  language "C" does not exist`. I'll digg into that. Thanks a lot for your help.